# Standing during the Aseres HaDibros

Tags: halacha, minhag, torah-reading, standing-sitting, aseres-hadibros

There are people that always stand by Laining and people that always sit. Among those that sit there are those that stand at certain points, such as the Aseres HaDibros or the Shira, etc. Is it proper to accord special honor to specific parts of the Torah over others?

Comment: Do you have a source for the _always stand_ group?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand him correctly, *Igros Moshe* (OC4 22, IIRC) says that one may stand during the *dibros* so as to accord them honor and must do so if the rest of the congregation is doing so but that if he is concerned that that makes it seem like they're the only important part of the *tora* then he should stand also during the rest of the reading that day. As always, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR) for a practical ruling.

Answer (score 6):

See here:
http://www.mesora.org/StandingDibros.html

The Rambam was opposed to it. yet this is near universal custom.

R' Soloveitchik and R' Moshe explain why it is not a problem.

Comment: How near? (My experience with the universe is relatively limited, so I'm just curious.)

Comment: i don't know. i've always seen standing. but i was just paraphrasing the article: "takes up the contradiction between the near universal practice of standing..."

Comment: Josh, spend some time with Aheinu B'nei Sferad V'Eidot HaMizrah. They do not stand for any Kriat HaTorah and definitely do not stand just for certain parts (at least according to the Minhag Yerushalmi and Hacham Ovadiya Yosef Shlit"a.