# Standing For Reading of Decalogue

Tags: halacha, rambam, torah-reading, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, standing-sitting

Poskim are recorded [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5424/standing-during-the-aseres-hadibros) permitting standing specifically for the Torah reading of the Aseres Hadibros.  Are there any poskim who forbid this in accordance with the ruling of the Rambam?

Comment: I'd have to check to be sure, but I think that Rav Soloveitchik was one of those. Check הררי קדם (on Moadim).

Comment: Har'rei Kedem is actually cited in the paper cited in the above link as ruling that given that taam haelyon is used, the reading is clearly characterised not as kriyas hatorah; institutionalized talmud Torah, but rather as a formal re-creation of maamud har sinai. THus, the Rambam's problem wouldnt exist since it was nly when taaam hatachton was used classifying it as normal kiyas hatorah.  Only then would standing negatively impact the standing of the rest of the Torah.  Personally this seems overly lomdish, as I imagine that using different trop will only make it seem even more important.

Comment: What is the Rambam's ruling and what is his reasoning?

Comment: @ElShteiger Rambam writes in a tshuva (I saw it in P'er Hador) but dont have one with me right now that it shouldnt be done because it gives the incorrect message that the rest of the Torah is less important than the aseres hadibros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Dose of Halacha](http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/please-remain-seated-sitting-during.html) who brings various opinions on this debate:

> While many Achronim including R’ Moshe Feinstein (Igros Moshe OC 4:22) justify standing, R’ Ovadia Yosef (Yechaveh Daas 1:29) writes that had they seen Rambam’s responsum they wouldn’t have written what they did.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Eliyashiv (Vayshima Moshe 5:pg.34) held that one should not stand for the aseres hadibros. He held that those who stand and then sit for the rest of the parsha is lessening the honor of the rest of the parsha.

Rav Eliyashiv holds that even in a place where most of the congregation stands one should still remain seated and does not have to worry about lo sisgodidu.